# Python: Why is converting a generator to a list taking so long

Tags: python, generator

Whilst creating some JSON output for an API I am using a generator to ensure that the the conversion process is scalable, and then transforming its output to a list so that is can be inserted into a larger JSON object as a list of JSON objects (this_list).

<strike>Iterating through the</strike> Creating the generator is fast enough - 1-200ms for 100 items - but then converting the generator to a list is taking around 10 seconds:

```
def create_a_list_of_objects(dataset):

    these_items = (do_some_processing_to_each_item(item) for item in dataset)

    >>> 0.15

    convert_to_list = list(these_items)

    >>> 8.75

    return convert_to_list

json.dumps({

   this_list: create_a_list_of_objects(datset)

})
```

If I just run it directly through a list comprehension then it takes around 10 seconds to complete.

```
return [do_some_processing_to_each_item(item) for item in dataset]

>>> 10.41
```

If I break it out into an explicit loop then each iteration of do_some_processing_to_each_item takes around 0.03, and around 3 seconds in total (I'm assuming that the difference between this and the list comprehension is due to the size of the output of do_some_processing_to_each_item: a reasonably large dictionary).

<strike>Why is this last step taking so long, and</strike> is there a faster way of converting the output of a generator to a list?

Is there an alternative strategy that would be both scalable and fast?

**Edits**

In response to the comments I've added additional information to the original post.

Comment: What is the timing of the single `do_some_processsing_to_each_item` call?

Comment: Where do you do the "iterating through the generator"?  In your code, no such iteration is happening outside of the `list` call itself.  So far, nothing you've shown is incompatible with the idea that it's `do_some_processing_to_each_item` which is slow.

Comment: Im not sure you understand how generators work ... there is literally no reason to use one in the sample code provided

Comment: could it be that the json.dumps is actually the part taking 10 seconds? if so, that's because it involves a lot of string conversion and manipulation

Comment: Why not use list composition directly, something like: `return [do_some_processing_to_each_item(item) for item in dataset]`

Comment: Something strange must be happening, because I can convert a generator that yields 10000000 values in less than 10 seconds.  You probably should profile your code to find the true hotspot(s).  I recommend a line-oriented profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not "iterating through the generator" in the above code (except intrinsically when you create the list), so unless you're doing that separately you don't have a benchmark. Your generator expression

```
(do_some_processing_to_each_item(item) for item in dataset)
```

just *creates* a generator; the processing doesn't happen until `these_items.__next__()` is called (as it is for every item when you loop over `these_items`).

To rule out list creation/storage as the bottleneck, you could just time this:

```
for item in these_items:
    do_some_processing_to_each_item(item)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I had misunderstood where the action happens when using the generator i.e. not in the creation of the generator itself, but whilst it is being iterated within list().

Answer (score 0):

Why not use list composition directly, something like:

```
return [do_some_processing_to_each_item(item) for item in dataset]
```

Comment: While this is a valid suggestion, it is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: @user2357112 the BDFL say this can dramatically improve speed